# Precision of a resulting number

Tags: j

[8th problem of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)
Here is the solution:

```
>./13*/\"."0 s
```

where:

```
s =: '731671765313306249192251196744265747423.......00823257530420752963450'
```

In other words this long number in a form of a string.

This solution works great, but it gives result:

```
2.35146e10
```

Which is correct, but I want to get full number:

```
2351462400
```

I know already that in J for this purposes letter 'x' is used. 
But how to apply it in this occasion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Extended Precision verb `x:` but you may also want to put an `x` after the 13 to ensure that you don't lose precision in the partial products.

```
x: >./13x*/\"."0 s
```

Information on the Extended Precision verb can be found here: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dxco.htm